# is this the right logic for selenium webdriver edge in python to a debugger address?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am importing the right modules, but I keep getting an error. I thought the above is how you open edge with a debugger address. Is the below, correct? I took out my webriver path and debugger address, but is the logic, right?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

ser = Service("")

op = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

op.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "")

bezinga = webdriver.Edge(service = ser, options = op)

print('edge connected')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove unnecessary imports unrelated to Edge like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
```

Than, initialize the proper objects and assign the debugger address:

```
edge_service = Service("<your_edge_driver_path>")
debugger_address = "<your_debugger_address>"

edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", debugger_address)

bezinga = webdriver.Edge(service=edge_service, options=edge_options)

print('Microsoft Edge Connected')
```

Comment: So I use the above and it came back with webdriver does not have AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Options'. Did you mean: 'IeOptions'?

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade selenium`  in cmd and again execute the code

Comment: Tried that but still got the error message:

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at 
from chrome not reachable

Comment: Options is now EdgeOptions() as well, anybody have anymore ideas?